# Linking with another start-up file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I am trying to link a program with my own start-up file by using the `STARTUP` directive in a LD script:

```
...
ENTRY(_start)
STARTUP(my_crt1.o)
...
```

GCC driver is used to link the program (not to bother with library paths like libgcc, etc.):

```
gcc -T my_script.ld ...
```

Unfortunately, it only works with a GCC compiled for powerpc targets, while arm or i686 targets don't and still include crt0.o in collect2. For example:

```
arm-eabi-g++ -v -T my_script.ld ...
```

gives me:

```
collect2 ... /opt/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8.0/../../../../arm-eabi/lib/crt0.o ...
```

and thus:

```
crt0.S:101: multiple definition of `_start'
```

It seems the `STARTUP` directive is totally ignored (the powerpc target uses its default crt0 too unless the `STARTUP` directive is specified) and there is no way to disable the default crt0.

Is there a portable way to link against another start-up file?

My start-up file uses `libgcc` functions (to call ctors and dtors) so `crtbegin.o`, `crtend.o`, etc. are needed so I would like to avoid the `-nostartfiles` option which disables `crt*.o` - I need to disable `crt0.o` only.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limitation indeed forces you to disable the default startup files with `-nostartfiles` (I prefer `-nostdlib`). You then need to build by yourself the list of run-time objects. gcc has the option `-print-file-name` to print the absolute path of libraries it was compiled with (crtbegin.o, crtend.o, libgcc.a...). For example: `arm-eabi-g++ <FLAGS> -print-file-name=crtbegin.o`

Here is the GNU Make macro I use (providing gcc and cflags):

```
define m.in/toolchain/gnu/locate =
$(strip
  $(shell $(m.in/toolchain/gnu/bin/gcc) $(m.in/toolchain/gnu/cflags) \
          -print-file-name=$(m.in/argv/1))
)
endef

crtn := $(call m.in/toolchain/gnu/locate, crtn.o)
```

Answer (score 7):

> I am trying to link a program with my own start-up file ...
>   GCC driver is used to link the program ...

In that case, you *must* also supply `-nostartfiles` flag to GCC.

Comment: I was dreaming of another solution :( In that case, how can you know if the target libgcc need crti.o or crtn.o ?

Comment: and it does not explain why it works with a cross-tools for powerpc.

Comment: It may be that the cross tools for power pc silently ignore duplicate symbols, and prefer the ones you explicitly supply. Just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks, I just spent 3 hours chasing this problem. Weak symbols were a bad, bad idea.