# compiling assembly(.s) files in cmake

Tags: c, assembly, cmake, wind-river-workbench

I am working on an embedded project with windriver compiler
The obj file(crt0.o) has the starting point(contains “main”) as per compiler design.
In my project, we have written our own assemlbly file(crt0.s).
now i want to compile this into crt0.o and put it for linking.
I tried the below way,

```
file(GLOB src_pbl ${BOOT_DIR}/pbl/src/.c
                  ${BOOT_DIR}/pbl/src/crt0.s
                  ${BOOT_DIR}/common/FlexCAN/.c)
add_executable(pbl ${src_pbl})
```

But it is not working. The crt0.s file is not getting compiled into crt0.o file. the linker took the crt0.o file from the default compiler path.

am I passing the .s file correctly to the target?

Comment: Your `file(GLOB)` invocation is wrong. It expects glob expressions like `*.c` or `${BOOT_DIR}/pbl/src/*.c`, but what you pass to it is a mix of exact files and non-complete glob expressions (they lack for `*`). "the linker took the crt0.o file from the default compiler path." - Linker uses default `crt0.o` unless you disable using default startup files. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639792/linking-with-another-start-up-file) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already you need to `enable_language(ASM)` for your project, or one of the other assembly compilers ie `ASM_ATT` or `ASM_MASM` etc. This has to be done before the `project` function.

Also don't use `file(GLOB)`, use `target_sources` instead.

I do it like this:

```
enable_language(ASM)

project(${METADATA_NAME})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        #
        #   assembler
        #
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/_start.s

        #
        #   c++
        #
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Main.cpp
)
```

Comment: In addition to that, I had to provide a compiler for the assembly files. Before the project function, I added `set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER $ENV{TOOLPATH_COMPILER}/ccarm)` to provide to asm the correct compiler.